# plot graph of function with different constants

Tags: plotting, graphics, functions, physics

I need to plot the graph of  :

$v(t) = \frac{-mg}{b} (e^{-\frac{b}{m}t}+1)$ , where $ g = 9.8 m/s^2$ and $b$ and $m$ are positive constants.

Is there a way to plot this without having to define random values for $b$ and $m$? I mean a way in which I can see how the graph behaves for different values of $b$ and $m$ ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I am new to Mathematica, I only know the basics

Comment: I will take a look, thank you !

Comment: To simplify little bit, you can introduce a new variable, say $\lambda=\frac{b}{m}$. Then you can `Plot` a sequence of curves for a list of $\lambda$ values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
v[s_, t_] := -g/s (Exp[-s t] + 1)
g = 9.8;
slist = {0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8};
Plot[Evaluate[v[#, t] & /@ slist], {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotTheme -> {"BoldColors", "Frame", "Grid"},
 FrameLabel -> {Automatic, v[t]},
 FrameStyle -> Directive[14, Black],
 PlotLabels -> slist
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: `Plot[Evaluate[v[slist, t] , {t, 0, 10},...]`  works too.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann That is good suggestion, it makes the syntax more transparent.